# How to call image in model class and put it in a list?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to put images from assets to my `listview(listtile)`. I have a Product model class which gets the product name and price.

I have no idea what data type I should use in model class to get image. And put the image in the `ListTile`

`ProductModel.dart`

```
  String name;
  int price;

  ProductModel(String name, int price){
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
  }
}
```

`ProductScreen.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../ProductModel.dart';


class ProductScreen2 extends StatelessWidget {
  final ValueSetter<ProductModel> _valueSetter;

  ProductScreen2(this._valueSetter);

  List<ProductModel> products = [
    ProductModel("Grey Jacket", 100),
    ProductModel("Brown Pants", 60),
    ProductModel("Grey Pants", 50),
    ProductModel("Orange Pants", 70),
    ProductModel("Long Jeans", 80),
    ProductModel("Black and Blue Cap", 40),
    ProductModel("Black Cap", 30),
    ProductModel("Red Cap", 35),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: ListView.separated(
          itemBuilder: (context, index){
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(products[index].name),
              trailing: Text("\RM${products[index].price}", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent, fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),),
              onTap: (){
                _valueSetter(products[index]);
              },
            );
          },
          separatorBuilder: (context, index){
            return Divider();
          },
          itemCount: products.length
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The goal is to show product images from my assets folder to the `ListTile` which now already contains my product name and price.

Comment: Hey you could write your model more concisely like                                                                    
`  String name;
  int price;
  String image

  ProductModel(this.name, this.price, this.image);
  `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use String in this case.

```
  String name;
  int price;
  String image

  ProductModel(String name, int price, String image){
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.image = image;
  }
```

Then use this like:

`Image.asset(productModel.image)`

Here `productModel` is an instance of `ProductModel` and `image` should be your asset image path.

Comment: What if you want to store the image in memory? would storing it in a base64 string be a good choice?